# Class Declaration in C#

Tags: c#, class, generics

I was searching for reusable Grid for MVC .Net. I found one open source Grid.

In the code I found a pretty interesting class declaration which I didn't understand
.
Can anybody tell me a detailed description of class declaration below:

```
public class Grid<TEntity, TSearchForm> : IGrid where  TSearchForm : SearchForm, new()
{
}
```

Also how do I create an instance of this class?

Comment: What part of this do you not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class is a generic class, it implements `IGrid`.

The two generic type parameters are `TEntity` and  `TSearchForm`.

`TSearchForm` is constrained to be `SearchForm` or a type that inherits from `SearchForm` and that it has a default constructor.

Suggested reading:

- [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)
- [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @RahulRajput - It is not a constructor. It is a class declaration.

Answer (score 6):

- Grid class implements IGrids interface.
- TSearchFormType must be of type SearchForm (by derivation)
- TSeachForm must have a constructor without parameters

Answer (score 6):

This is generic class inherited from IGrid with two parameters: TEntity, TSearchForm.

Also there is a constraint on type of TSearchForm:

1. it must be of type SearchForm or below it in hierarchy (able to cast to SearchForm implicitly)
2. TSearchForm must have public parameterless constructor.

More info:

[where (generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)
[new Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

Comment: No, this is a Generic class declaration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f(v=vs.100).aspx). You will be able to use TEntity, TSearchForm types inside it for your purposes.